# Styling of WPF Chart AreaSerie in program

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit

I need to create area series in WPF chart toolkit in a program, but I do not know how to change a color of serie.

Setting of PathStyle doesn't work even in XAML. According to source files area series should be binded to background color but this doesn't work either.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a hard time also figuring out how to change colors. Changing Background colours or ColorPalette didn't seem to do anything. I solved the issue, for the LineSeries, by settings the background with a setter in the style ( the DataPointStyle of the LineSeries, which applies on a DataPoint)
 so in vb :

```
    Dim NLS = New LineSeries()
    NLS.IndependentValuePath = "Time"
    NLS.DependentValuePath = "Quantity"
    NLS.Title = " Quantity in function of time"
    NLS.ItemsSource = MyItemSource
    Dim ThisStyle As New Style(GetType(DataPoint))
    ThisStyle.Setters.Add(New Setter(BackgroundProperty, New SolidColorBrush(MyWantedColor)))
    NLS.DataPointStyle = ThisStyle
```

I hope this can help you solve your issue for the Area Series.

Comment: Thank you for your help. In AreaSerie there is no DataPoint, but Path instead. Even I configured fill brush  the same way, it doesn't work.  I am quite surprise there are so many article about great way to customize this chart,  but it doesn't work.

Comment: Well since it doesn't work for you, you may have to do  a terrible thing : look into the xaml/code behind provided with the lib. (Or do the drawing yourself in a good old canvas. In my case, that would have been faster :-( )